# Do platform device drivers have to be registered with a major and minor number.?

Tags: linux-device-driver

I am new to device driver writing and I need to write a SPI driver to access flash memory for a embedded linux running on ARM.

What I don't understand is, do I need to register the driver with a major and minor number? Or do platform device drivers also need a major and minor number?

If yes, When and How to assign it?
I guess, I'll be using `platform_driver_register()` for registering the driver.

Comment: You're probably confused by looking at **Linux/drivers/spi/**.  Those "SPI drivers" are for SPI *master* controllers.  A SPI flash chip is a SPI *slave* device, and requires a SPI protocol driver.  Study http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/spi/spi-summary  A SPI protocol driver is located in the subdirectory of the slave device's functionality (rather than its interface).  Take a look at **drivers/mtd/devices/m25p80.c** and **sst25l.c** for examples.

Comment: Where can I read more about these terms (SPI Protocol Driver, SPI Master Controller) for getting more understanding in this event?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to register major or minor numbers. Your question is actually not precise enough. Do you want to write a driver for a specific SPI flash or a driver for an SPI host?

- If this is an SPI flash, what you want is to register your driver using a `struct spi_driver` with `module_spi_driver()` then in the probe, register your device in the MTD susbsystem using `mtd_device_parse_register`. The MTD susbsystem will register the major and minors for you.
- If you need to write a driver for the host, then you will register your driver using a `struct platform_driver` and `module_platform_driver()`. In your probee you will register your hosts using `spi_register_master`

You should probably read a bit about the Linux device model for further explanations.

Comment: I have to access (read and write) this flash [SST26VF016](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/25017A.pdf). So @Alexandre, I guess I need to look into MTD subsystem in detail.

Comment: I didn't have a thorough look at the datashet but I guess you should build on drivers/mtd/spi-nor/spi-nor.c